# Render text depending on matching API Results - Axios/JS

Tags: javascript, axios

I have this working, but it does consume quite a lot of space.

I'm wondering if there is way to refactor it more, matching API results with a smaller refactored condition, perhaps?

#### axios.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const Models = () => { 
  return axios.get('data/cars.json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
}
```

#### file.js

```js
import { Models } from './axios';
let carModels = Models();


carModels.then((result) => {
    var i, j, match;
    match = false;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < result[i].countries.length; j++) {
        if (result[i].countries[j].price == price &&
          result[i].color == color &&
          result[i].brand == brand &&
          result[i].model == model &&
          result[i].speed == speed) 
          {
             match = true;
             return document.querySelector('#brandTitle').textContent = result[i].brand;
          }
      }
  }
  if (match == false) {
    console.log('No match found.');
  }
})
```

Comment: how is this even working you are using return statement in for loop

Comment: Its imported into a MutationOberserver function. It returns data, and Im using that data in the Observer.

Comment: You are changing DOM value if your conditions met, and its id selector so I am assuming you would be getting only one match right?

Comment: Correct, I am declaring already the value/content for color/speed/model, but its not in the example above.

And I get one match correct, I check the API response and the results are correct.

Comment: let me know below workaround helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `some()` that will make sure to terminate the loop as conditions met

```
carModels.then(result => {
    var i, j, match;
    match = false;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        match = result[i].countries.some(country => {
            if (
                country.price == price &&
                result[i].color == color &&
                result[i].brand == brand &&
                result[i].model == model &&
                result[i].speed == speed
            ) {
                document.querySelector('#brandTitle').textContent = result[i].brand;
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    if (match == false) {
        console.log('No match found.');
    }
});
```

to make more efficient you can use `some` on parent loop also

```
carModels.then(result => {
    var match;
    match = false;
    result.some(res => {
        match = result[i].countries.some(country => {
            if (
                country.price == price &&
                res.color == color &&
                res.brand == brand &&
                res.model == model &&
                res.speed == speed
            ) {
                document.querySelector('#brandTitle').textContent = res.brand;
                return;
            }
        });
        if (match) {
            return;
        }
    });
    if (match == false) {
        console.log('No match found.');
    }
});
```

Comment: works, many thanks! So `some()` ends the looping once the match is found.

Comment: yes that is correct , learn more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some